# Live CD Boot not working

Tags: 14.04, boot, live-cd, crash

so I'm trying since yesterday to use Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (Trusty Tahr) (AMD64) from a live cd.

My computer does recognize that it is Ubuntu, and it begins loading until the "loading screen with the five dots" when it seems to try to load until giving up and reboots my computer, sending me back to windows 10.

Tried to use the "check for error" CD option but it told me everything was ok.

I don't know what I have to tell you from my config so please ask if you need anything.

And I tried both UEFI and Legacy boot methods. Same crash.

Comment: Do you have NVIDIA graphics?

Comment: Nope, AMD (AMD Radeon™ HD 8970M)

Comment: Hmm. Is Secure Boot on in the BIOS?

Comment: Um, that option doesn't appear. (Bios is ATOMBIOSBK-AMD)

Comment: Can you try making a LiveUSB instead, maybe with Ubuntu 15.10?

Comment: That already failed (same type of crash) yesterday. Tested live cd/usb with both 15.10 and 14.04

Answer (score 0):

Small update, I noticed a very short frame before the loading screen that is :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEq1c.jpg